# Dailymotion PHP API Video Upload

Tags: dailymotion-api

I hope I am not submitting a duplicate question, but I have not been able to find an answer to what I want to do.

I have a script to authenticate an API for login to link a users account on one web site to their Dailymotion Account.  But I am not finding a way to upload a video to that users account without passing their Dailymotion username and password, which I do not want to try to capture on our system.

Does anyone have an example of a PHP script to pass a token back and the parameters I need to pass to Dailymotion?

I simply want to be able to allow an authenticated user who has linked their account on Dailymotion on a website to upload a video to their account on Dailymotion.  :-)  I just can't find the right parameters I need to pass on the Developer site or an example script that does not use the users login credentials and uses the API Key/Secret on the test scripts I am using.

Thanks in advance. Any links or knowledge you can pass my way would be great.

Thanks

MrPepik

Answer (score 0):

your question does not seem very clear, what have you tried so far?  Documentation on authentication in Dailymotion API is available at http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#authentication and there is a PHP SDK you can use (http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#sdk-php).

Anyway, your user definitely needs to pass his username and password at some point in order to get an access token, but this can be done using the token (or implicit) grant type which redirects the user to an authorization page on Dailymotion. Your script is called back once the end-user authorized your API key to access the Dailymotion service on its behalf. PHP documentation can be found at http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#sdk-php-authentication

Comment: Hi Dailymotion,

Sorry for not responding sooner, I didn't get the email notification from Stackoverflow.  

In the Dailymotion.php SDK, I should be able to use GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION, I use another script for API authentication for a user, I then take and store the refresh_token, access_token, and expire date in a database.

Comment: I should be able to pull this information and pass it through to the Dailymotion.php SDK, but it looks like the script is looking for Cookie variables.  IE:  $session['refresh_token'] and $session['grant_type'].  
Is there a way I can pull my tokens from a DB and pass them through to the Dailymotion.php SDK without re-writing the Dailymotion.php script to use the tokens I have stored?  
I have tried using straight curl scripts, but even though the API is authenticated by my test user I keep getting the message that I need to pass through the manage_video scope.

Comment: I pass this through on the original API Authentication request and I am using those tokens.

Comment: All of this is thoroughly explained in the documentation here:
http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation/#sdk-php-overloading